# Ubuntu shell script save second file of the directory as a variable

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

My question is I need to write a script which will take the second file in the directory as input. I can't simply write the name of the second file into the script because the script will be used for various directories with different file names. Thus I would like to set the name of the second file of the directory as a variable but could not find a way to do so.

Any help will be much appreciated as I am fairly new to shell scripts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your filenames don't contain linebreaks (which is most often the case) or similar pitfalls,

```
f=$(ls | head -n 2| tail -n1)
```

This takes the first two files and then the last of them.
Here is the 8th file, taken with help of sed:

```
time f=$(ls | sed -n '8p')
```

And here a line break agnostic solution:

```
n=1; for f in * ; do if (( $n == 11 )); then echo $f; break; fi; ((++n)); done 
line break.bad

f=$(ls | sed -n '11p'); echo $f; 
line
```

The file was made with

```
touch "line
break.bad"
```

Comment: That's fine. You normally express `problem solved` by upvoting and accepting the answer (icons hitting on the left `^` or `v` and the check mark). This way, other people searching for answer can see in the overview, how many upvoted answers a question got and if the person, who asked the question, accepted one as solution. The check mark can be later reassigned to another answer, if  a better answer occurs.